# How to detect an inconsistent pattern of coordinates?

Tags: algorithm

For simplicity lets assume that I have a list of X,Y coordinates. X has a limited range of 0-100 mm, and Y has 0 - inf mm. Every iteration a new list of coordinates is received. All the coordinates where the delta between their Y to the last Y is bigger then a configurable value (lets say 300M) are removed from the list.

I need to find an algorithm that will help me select all the co-ordinates that are repeating in a pattern.

I have a way of solving this problem but I would prefer a more "methodical" way.

For example, Lets say I have a list with the following coordinates (X, Y): 
(2, 9), (2, 18), (2, 27), (2, 54), (2, 63), ...
Y delta is configured as 9mm.

Almost all Y deltas are 9 except between the 3rd and the 4th coordinates. Those coordinates are missing but still it is a pattern and the algorithm should be able to tell that all those coordinates are from the same pattern.

Another example:
(2, 9), (2, 13), (2, 18), (2, 22), (2, 27), (2, 54), (2, 63), ...

Here I expect the same result as the first example even though there are more coordinates that are not part of the pattern.

I need to be able to know exactly which coordinates are in the detected pattern.

Comment: So the pattern for the first example is (x=2, dy=9), except when it isn't? Do you want to detect that you have points (2, 36) and (2, 45) missing, but include all the other points?

Comment: What should be the output? Corrected list? Just list of missing coordinates? Yes/No whether anything is missing? The delta? What about ys= 2, 4, 7 , what is the correct answer for them? Does X play any role at all?

Comment: In all your examples, X=2.So why do you even mention X ?

Comment: @Useless, Yes this is the pattern. I don't care about the missing points I just want to detect all the existing points that match the pattern.

Comment: @Quimby , the output should be a new list containing all the points matching the pattern.

Comment: So should (2,54) count as fitting the pattern, even though its dy>9? Or do you just want to look for `y_n = y_0 + n * k` for some `k` (here, k=9)?

Comment: @alonl Okay, but if the ys are (1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 25, 30) then what's the supposed correct delta for the arithmetic sequence?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Since I discussed in the question about coordinates I wanted to write  it for better understanding this Y values are part of the coordinates I was writing about.

Comment: @alonl: then mentioning X is added noise that makes the understanding more difficult.

Comment: @alonl, when you say a **pattern**, you are referring to points that match some function and, in fact, any function that can be written in as a formal mathematical expression. (your examples are just that, examples). Unless you share with your algorithm what the function is, I see no way to solve this problem. If, for instance, your function is _start from any number and increase the next one by **n**..._, then you are providing a formal algorithm that can be used both to find **n** and then to identify the points you are looking for.

Comment: @Useless, Yes (2, 54) is part of the pattern. every existing point the is a multiplicity of 9 is.

Comment: Right, so the dY condition you mention is neither sufficient nor necessary. What you're actually looking for is the equation from my previous comment, right?

Comment: At first, I would think if digital filter or fourier transform fits in this case

Comment: @Quimby, the y delta is a constant configure beforehead. I Added it to the example.

Comment: wait, you mean you're only looking for dy = 9? Nothing else?

Comment: "all the co-ordinates that are repeating in a pattern": there are no repetitions in the examples, can't make sense of your question.

Comment: @Useless Yes. for a given Dy. Find the pattern.

Comment: But if you know a fixed dY, you know what the pattern is. All you're looking for is a list of the elements with some multiple of your fixed dY, right?

Comment: @alonl It is very unclear what you are asking. If you say that Dy is fixed, that is your pattern.

Comment: @Useless, Yes you are right. this is the solution I have. I'm searching for other solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The deltas of the first example are

```
9 9 27 9
```

and you can observe that the most frequent is `9`, which is a divisor of `27`, and with some good will, you can infer that two data points are missing.

The deltas of the second are

```
-5 14 4 5 27 9
```

and it makes no sense to see a pattern there.

Comment: Fixed the second example.
There is a pattern for the second example. (2, 13)  and (2, 22) are just noise.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the patterns you want are in small-shift deltas and GCDs.  Since the first example solves pretty quickly, let's look at the second.

```
9, 13, 18, 22, 27, 54, 63
```

Here, the shift-1 (e.g. 13-9, 54-27) and shift-2 (18-9, 54-22) deltas are

```
  4,  5,  4,  5,  27, 9
    9,  9,  9, 32, 36
```

and the GCDs of those adjacent deltas (e.g. (4,5), (27,9), or (9, 9) ) are

```
    1,  1,  1,  1,  9
      9,  9,  1, 1
```

This makes `9` a very strong suspect, being the only non-unity value in the list.  A second pass to look for multiples of `9` will easily reveal the preponderance of such values.  Non-conforming values get removed; multiples of 9 indicate that we need to impute missing values.

You can hard-code those searches in your favorite language.  Many modern languages have one or two packages that will handle such a shift with a simple operator; in Python, both `numpy` and `pandas` will do this.

Can you take it from there?